# RMI: thread waiting on server side

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

I have the following code:

```
public interface RmiServer extends Remote{
   public String getMessage()throws RemoteException;
}

public class DefaultRmiServer implements RmiServer{
  private LinkedBlockingQueue<String> queue;

  @Override
  public String getMessage()throws RemoteException{
    return queue.take();
  }
  ...
}
```

When rmi client calls `getMessage()` method it is clear that there can be two situations:

1. there is a message in queue and method returns
2. there is `no` message in queue and thread is waiting

What will happen in the second case with this rmi call? How long the client will wait?

Comment: By default, forever.

Comment: if you want to make this a more robust api, i would suggest implementing a method which takes a "long waitTime" which allows the client to control how long they are willing to wait (instead of relying on the rmi timeout which is a "global" value for the jvm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sun RMI client connection's timout is being controlled by the property `sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout`, which is by default set to no timeout (=waits forever).

> **sun.rmi.transport.tcp.responseTimeout (1.4 and later):**
>
> The value of
> this property represents the length of time (in milliseconds) that the
> client-side Java RMI runtime will use as a socket read timeout on an
> established JRMP connection when reading response data for a remote
> method invocation. Therefore, this property can be used to impose a
> timeout on waiting for the results of remote invocations; if this
> timeout expires, the associated invocation will fail with a
> java.rmi.RemoteException. Setting this property should be done with
> due consideration, however, because it effectively places an upper
> bound on the allowed duration of any successful outgoing remote
> invocation. The maximum value is Integer.MAX_VALUE, and a value of
> zero indicates an infinite timeout. The default value is zero (no
> timeout).

For the list of this and other parameters that can used to control RMI connections see [sun.rmi Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html)